# Can rice be brought into Hawaii?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, hawaii, honolulu

I bought 10lb of rice at a local grocery store in Phoenix, Arizona and wish to take it to Honolulu, Hawaii. The rice is well packed and sealed. It's a variety of rice I get in my home country and is not available in Honolulu (that I know of). Can I fly with it into HNL(Honolulu)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rice does [not appear](https://hdoa.hawaii.gov/pi/pq/travel-shipping-information/traveling-from-the-u-s-mainland-to-hawai%CA%BBi/) to be a controlled item.

> In general, foods that are cooked, canned, frozen or commercially processed and/or packaged are allowed to be transported to Hawaii, as long as the product is arriving from within the U.S.

I would be surprised if there are types of rice unavailable in Honolulu, but since you have bought already bought a large package…

Comment: Indeed, Hawai'i is one of the destinations of choice for Japanese citizens.

Comment: Asian rice should be easy to find in Hawaii. I thought it might be Italian risotto rice, which can be tricky to find.

Comment: Risotto rice should be fine too. I think most if not all Whole Foods carry it.